# How do I plot a hemisphere on top of a cone?

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot a hemisphere on top of a cone to create something that looks like an ice cream cone. Here is what I have so far:

```
Show[ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 4, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 4}, AxesLabel -> Automatic], ContourPlot3D[y^2 + z^2 == (x - 4)^2, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 4}, AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> Automatic]]
```

From here, how do I get to a shape that resembles an ice cream cone? Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 3):

> ...is there a way to do this with `ContourPlot3D[]`?

It's certainly doable. As an exercise, figure out how the equations used in the following code were derived:

```
iceCreamProfile[r_, h_, x_] := Piecewise[{{Sqrt[r^2 - x^2], x > 0}}, r (1 + x/h)]

With[{r = 1, h = GoldenRatio}, 
     ContourPlot3D[iceCreamProfile[r, h, z]^2 == x^2 + y^2,
                   {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, -h, r},
                   BoxRatios -> Automatic, Mesh -> None]]
```

[image: cone]

With a little more work,

```
With[{r = 1, h = GoldenRatio}, 
     ContourPlot3D[iceCreamProfile[r, h, z]^2 == x^2 + y^2,
                   {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, -h, r},
                   BoxRatios -> Automatic, Lighting -> "Neutral",
                   Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
                   MeshShading -> {ColorData["Legacy", "Wheat"],
                                   ColorData["Legacy", "HotPink"]}]]
```

[image: fancy cone]

Answer (score 2):

you can use `Graphics3D` with graphics primitives `Cone` and `Sphere` (using [`ClipPlanes`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClipPlanes.html) to get a half-sphere):

```
Graphics3D[{Directive[Orange, Opacity[1], Specularity[White, 10]], 
  Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1}}, 1/2], 
  Directive[Brown, Opacity[1], Specularity[White, 30]], 
  {ClipPlanes -> {0, 0, 1, 0}, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1/2]}}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use  [`RevolutionPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RevolutionPlot3D.html):

```
Show[RevolutionPlot3D[{t/2, t}, {t, 0, 1/2}, Mesh -> None, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Orange, Opacity[1], Specularity[White, 10]]],
  RevolutionPlot3D[{Cos[t]/4, Sin[t]/4 + 1/2}, {t, 0, Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Brown, Opacity[1], Specularity[White, 30]], 
   Mesh -> None], 
  PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to do this with ContourPlot3D[]?

Comment: @elizabethb, you can do something like `Show[ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 == (z/2)^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0,2}, 
 Mesh -> None, ContourStyle ->{Directive[Orange, Opacity[1], Specularity[White, 10]],Directive[Brown, Opacity[1], Specularity[White, 30]]}, Boxed->False, Axes->False],
 ContourPlot3D[ x^2 + y^2 + (z-2)^2 == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z,2, 3}, 
 ContourStyle->Directive[Brown, Opacity[1], Specularity[White, 30]]
,Mesh -> None], PlotRange->All, BoxRatios->Automatic]`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`RegionFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html):

```
Show[ContourPlot3D[
  x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 4, {x, -4, 0}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 4}, 
  ContourStyle -> Pink, Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
  Background -> Black], 
 ContourPlot3D[
  y^2 + z^2 == (x - 2)^2, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 4}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, y^2 + z^2 <= 4 && -4 < x < 2],
   MeshFunctions -> {#1 & , #2 & }], PlotRange -> Table[{-4, 4}, 3]]
```

[image]